# tableau grant total not giving me correct out put from calculated field

Tags: tableau-api

as my previous question i was not able to give sample data I have updated another question which will help to solve this problem

I have a sample excel file

[image]

using above data I have created tableau calculated field called bonus

```
if ISNULL(SUM([active])) 
then 0
ELSE
sum([Sale])*SUM([Per])
END
```

All my calculation is right however when I use Column grant total it coming wrong values.

[image]

How can I fix Grand total in tableau

Comment: Possible duplicate of [tableau calculated field column grant total not giving correct value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55303905/tableau-calculated-field-column-grant-total-not-giving-correct-value)

Comment: Hi Andy as I told my previous post it getting difficult for me to give all details with sample data that is why I have created another question which will give you more details my problem. Hope you would be able to help to solve that